# Filtering a TTable Where The FieldName Contains a Space

Tags: delphi

I wish to use the Filter Property of a TTable to filter a Table where the FieldName contains a space but the space causes the filter expresssion to be truncated at the space. For example; If the FieldName had been 'ErrorLevel' the Filter 'ErrorLevel>0' would work, hoever the FieldName is 'Error Level' and the Filter 'Error Level>0' raises an exception Class EDatabaseError ... Field'Error' not found.

Comment: Try `[Error Level]`. on a side note WHY would you create a field name containing spaces?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. That worked a teat. How on earth did you discover that?

I do not create the Table containing field names with embedded spaces. The Table is created by a component named TTUtility which is a wrapper around the Borland Paradox Table Repair utility.

Comment: Didn't you run that repair utility in some evil mode that it break the field names this way ? <g>

Comment: I remembered seeing it. I found the link, though, because it was in the list of "Related" links that appears to the right of this question (and was in the list of "Similar Questions" that appeared when you were typing your question, probably based on "Table", "Field Name", "Contain", and "Space" in your subject). :-)